# How do I add a file upload field to user profile?

Tags: users

I need to add a file upload field to user profile, and show it on profile page (not during registration). How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should implement [hook_user()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_user/6), and add code when the user edit form is being shown, and `$op` is equal to "form"; this is different from the form shown to the users when they are registering, which is handled when `$op` is equal to "register."

The hook documentation reports the following description for the "form" operation:

> The user account edit form is about to be displayed. The module should present the form elements it wishes to inject into the form.

To complete the information, on Drupal 7 the only way to add fields to the user edit form is to implement [hook_form_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7), or [hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/7); both the hooks are also used in Drupal 6, and they are the only way to remove form fields from the user edit form, while `hook_user()` allows to just add form fields.

Answer (score 3):

Use [Content Profile](http://drupal.org/project/content_profile).

By default Content Profile puts the additional fields in a tab on the profile page. If you want them to be all in one page use [Account Profile](http://drupal.org/project/account_profile)